# WebServiceGatewaySupport.setDefaultUri throwing NULL POINTER Exception only in Pre-Prod environment

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

Calling SOAP service application throwing the below error only in our *pre-prod* environment. The code is working in *dev* and *staging*. We're completely stuck here actually.

The application is not even getting deployed in the *pre-prod* environment. We tried to put debug logs and found the place where it is failing, the methods which are defined inside `WebServiceGateWaySupport` which are `setDefaultUri` etc. Since this issue is coming only on one instance, we're not sure what to do.

We've given the exception, which is being thrown, below.

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport.setDefaultUri(WebServiceGatewaySupport.java:92)
    at com.company.cabs.App.mapper.client.soapclient.AppClientConfiguration.setAppClient(AppClientConfiguration.java:53)
    at com.company.cabs.App.mapper.client.soapclient.AppClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f7933.CGLIB$setAppClient$0(<generated>)
    at com.company.cabs.App.mapper.client.soapclient.AppClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f7933$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d3fe050c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.company.cabs.App.mapper.client.soapclient.AppClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d9f7933.setAppClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.company.cabs.mpd.event.consumer.StarterApplication.main(StarterApplication.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

AppClientConfiguration.class

```java
@Configuration
public class AppClientConfiguration {

.....   
    @Bean
    public AppClient setAppClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller, AppClient client) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

        client.setDefaultUri(defaultUri); //Error is being thrown here
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);//Error is being thrown here
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);//Error is being thrown here
        client.getWebServiceTemplate().setMessageSender(webServiceMessageSender());//Error is being thrown here
        client.getWebServiceTemplate().setCheckConnectionForError(false);//Error is being thrown here
        client.getWebServiceTemplate().setCheckConnectionForFault(false);//Error is being thrown here
        ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = {new AppClientInterceptor()};
        client.setInterceptors(interceptors);

        return client;
    }
....

}
```

AppClient.java

```java
@Component
public class AppClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
....
}
```

Comment: Where does this `defaultUri` coming from, and are you sure it is configured appropriately for your pre-prod environment? In any case, the error suggests that the `webServiceTemplate` of `WebServiceGatewaySupport` is null, which as far as I can tell from a quick look at the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/main/spring-ws-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/client/core/support/WebServiceGatewaySupport.java) should not be possible.

Comment: Yes. `defaultUri` is configured in the properties. even i am able to print it inside the `setAppClient` method.

Comment: In any case, without a [mre] (including the exact version of spring-ws), this is likely not diagnosable.

Comment: sure @MarkRotteveel. will share that. BTW. this app is working fine in other environments. only in _pre-prod_ its failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution which worked for us is manually create an object of `AppClient` class.

1. Removed `@Component` annotation from `AppClient.java` class.
2. Inside `AppClientConfiguration.java` class

```
    @Bean
    public AppClient setAppClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        
        AppClient client = new AppClient();//Manually creating the object  
        client.setDefaultUri(defaultUri); 
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        ............
        ...........        
        return client;
    }
```

Not sure how the previous one is working in other instances. But , this approach is working.